# Code works in development but not production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, next.js, cloudinary

I'm using the following code to get images from Cloudinary and display in a simple gallery built using Next.js.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { CloudinaryContext, Image, Transformation } from 'cloudinary-react'
import axios from 'axios'
import Default from '@components/layouts/default'
import styles from '@styles/modules/gallery.module.css'

class Gallery extends Component {

  state = { images: [] };

  getImages() {
    axios.get('http://res.cloudinary.com/delpknfnx/image/list/something.json')
          .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data.resources);
            this.setState({ images: res.data.resources});
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getImages()
  }

  render() {

    const { images }  = this.state

    return (
      <Default
        pageTitle="Gallery"
      >
        <article className="wrapper">
          <h1>See our latest on the job snaps!</h1>

          <CloudinaryContext cloudName="delpknfnx">

            <div className={styles.gallery}>

                { images.map((data, index) => (
                  <div key={index}>
                      <h2>{data.context.custom.caption}</h2>

                      <Image 
                        publicId={data.public_id}
                        alt={data.context.custom.caption}
                        dpr="auto"
                        responsive
                        width="auto"
                        responsiveUseBreakpoints="true"
                        loading="lazy"
                      >
                        <Transformation
                          quality="auto"
                          fetchFormat="auto"
                        />
                      </Image>
                      <p>{data.context.custom.alt}</p>
                  </div>
                  ))}

            </div>
          </CloudinaryContext>
        </article>
      </Default>
    );
  }
}

export default Gallery
```

This works in development but when I push to Vercel nothing is rendered. I presume I need to use `getStaticProps` to fetch the data or something, but to be honest I'm out of my depth and don't know how to go about that.

If anyone could give me any pointers as to how I go about doing this then it would be much appreciated.

Relevent errors:

```
353-366f7d207b2d16799427.js:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://newtings.vercel.app/gallery/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://res.cloudinary.com/delpknfnx/image/list/something.json'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at t.exports (353-366f7d207b2d16799427.js:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.d.onerror (353-366f7d207b2d16799427.js:1)
```

Comment: "when I push to Vercel nothing is rendered" - Nothing at all, or just the images don't get rendered? Do you get any errors in the console? Is any request failing in the Network tab?

Comment: Nothing is rendered at all. Here is the live example: 
https://newtings.vercel.app/gallery/

Two errors in the console that are related (I think).

Comment: https:// ...... https://res.cloudinary.com/delpknfnx/image/list/something.json

Comment: Looks like a problem requesting http resources from a https page. Update the URL and remove the `http:` bit - the request will be made with whichever scheme the page was loaded over.

Comment: Ok sure I have added the errors to original question. I have also removed the http:// and pushed but same errors are there in the console.

This also breaks in development 'Error: Request failed with status code 404', unless I re-add http/https

Comment: Can you not put https there instead of http? Otherwise you would need to tweak the policies with which your page is served, I am not sure its possible in a managed plattform like vercel.

Comment: Ah cool thanks so much for your help everyone. @Madflow actually wrote the answer earlier and I missed it cheers :)